# how to use Extension normal_installed Reg key (NOT forcelist) for Edge and Chrome Browsers?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, deployment, registry, microsoft-edge, chromium

So I checked the latest documentation for Chromium Deployment.
There are the following policies:
Block​External​Extensions ​Extension​Allow​Insecure​Updates
​Extension​Allowed​Types ​Extension​Install​Blacklist ​Extension​Install​Forcelist
​Extension​Install​Sources ​Extension​Install​Whitelist  ​Extension​Settings

and normal_installed is not listed anymore.

I need a way to install an extension silently but give the users a choice to disable it if they want.

Comment: Which documentation you're referring to? I checked the [Chrome help doc](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9867568?hl=en) and there's still `normal_installed` in **installation_mode**. I also find [an article](https://textslashplain.com/2020/02/26/can-i-in-the-new-edge/) about Edge Chromium, it also says there's *installation_mode set to normal_installed*. It seems that we need to set it in [ExtensionSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensionsettings).

Comment: I will check. But I think its an old article.

Comment: The article is old but the document is the latest. Feel free to come back if you have any other issues.